# Password prompt when installing software

Tags: sudo, password

I want to disable the prompt for a password when installing a software and when launching a vpn client (torGard).

How can disable this?

What I've done:
in terminal >

```
sudo visudo /etc/sudoers/
```

1st I've changed

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

then ctrl + O (wich might be were I am wrong?)

It didn't do much so I've also changed the setting for `%sudo` and `%root`
but I am still prompt for those passwords. Any thing I would have missed?

Comment: How should we know if you've missed anything?

Comment: I assume you meant to spell `torGuard` and not `torGard`? This isn't an AskUbuntu question but you can go to their website: https://torguard.net/ and on-line chat tech support can walk you through their sign-on process. If you want to know how to setup Ubuntu with no User Password, post a different question.

Comment: account control is managed by the OS sir not the software developper. I can sing -in just fine. Ubuntu is prompting for the password.

Answer (score 0):

While logged on as yourself ( myusername ) issue this

```
sudo visudo
```

you will get a pwd prompt ... then put this new line at file bottom

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: NOPASSWD: ALL
```

of course replace myusername with your actual value 
... save with a ctrl-x ... enter a `Y` to confirm

enjoy and welcome to the world of linux